# Assigning module.exports to a function returned undefined method

Tags: node.js, coffeescript

I'm integrating breeze.js trying to duplicate this file([github](https://github.com/Breeze/breeze.js.samples/blob/master/node/zza-node-mongo/server/database.js)) to coffeescript and use it in my project. Right below is my translation and then I set `module.exports`.

```
d_b = (database) ->
    MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient
    db = null

    mongoURL = "mongodb://localhost/project_db"
    mongoOptions = server: {auto_reconnect: true}

    getDB = (next) ->
        console.log 'getDB()'
        if db
            next null, db

        else
            MongoClient.connect mongoUrl, mongoOptions, (err, project_db) ->
                if err
                    err.message = (err.message or '') + '\nIs the MongoDb server running?'
                    next err
                else
                    db = project_db
                    next null, db

    database.getDB = getDB
    return

module.exports = d_b
```

When I go to use it I get an error back.

```
# in another file
database = require '../database'
database.getDB (err, db) ->
    # ...

TypeError: Object function (database) {
    var MongoClient, db, getDB, mongoOptions, mongoURL;
    MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
    db = null;
    mongoURL = "mongodb://localhost/project_db";
    mongoOptions = {
      server: {
        auto_reconnect: true
      }
    };
    getDB = function(next) {
      console.log('getDB()');
      if (db) {
        return next(null, db);
      } else {
        return MongoClient.connect(mongoUrl, mongoOptions, function(err, project_db) {
          if (err) {
            err.message = (err.message || '') + '\nIs the MongoDb server running?';
            return next(err);
          } else {
            db = utourney_db;
            return next(null, db);
          }
        });
      }
    };
    database.getDB = getDB;
  } has no method 'getDB'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original code you're porting from is an immediately invoked function called with `module.exports` as the first parameter. So a more literal translation would be:

```coffeescript
((database) ->
    MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient
    db = null

    mongoURL = "mongodb://localhost/project_db"
    mongoOptions = server: {auto_reconnect: true}

    getDB = (next) ->
        console.log 'getDB()'
        if db
            next null, db

        else
            MongoClient.connect mongoUrl, mongoOptions, (err, project_db) ->
                if err
                    err.message = (err.message or '') + '\nIs the MongoDb server running?'
                    next err
                else
                    db = project_db
                    next null, db

    database.getDB = getDB
    return
)(module.exports)
```

In CoffeeScript, I'd probably write the module more like this:

```coffeescript
MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient
db = null

mongoURL = "mongodb://localhost/project_db"
mongoOptions = server: {auto_reconnect: true}

module.exports = (next) ->
    console.log 'getDB()'
    if db
        next null, db

    else
        MongoClient.connect mongoUrl, mongoOptions, (err, project_db) ->
            if err
                err.message = (err.message or '') + '\nIs the MongoDb server running?'
                next err
            else
                db = project_db
                next null, db
```

and then you'd use it like this:

```coffeescript
database = require '../database'
database (err, db) ->
  # ...
```

Comment: When I try and format it the way you answer it breaks the syntax or something. I get `Error: Cannot find module 'mongodb'` Seems I can't put anything outside a function or something

Comment: Do you have the `mongodb` Node module installed? Previously it was "working" (it only looked like it was) because you were never calling the function.

Comment: aha that was it. I'm switching from Mongoose and forgot that part.